# Issue filtering on relations in prisma

Tags: node.js, postgresql, model, nestjs, prisma

I have an interesting issue here. Below is my prisma schema:

```
model User {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  email String @unique
  password String
  first_name String
  last_name String
  phone String?
  bvn String?
  dob String?
  disabled Boolean @default(false)
  role  Roles @default(customer)
  verified Boolean @default(false)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  deleted_at DateTime?
  verifications Verification[]
  SentNotifications Notification[] @relation("SenderNotification")
  ReceivedNotifications Notification[] @relation("ReceiverNotification")
  SentChats Chat[] @relation("SenderChat")
  ReceivedChats Chat[] @relation("ReceiverChat")
  Goods Good[]
  CustomerDeliveries CustomerDelivery[] //1-m relationship
  CustomerDeliveryLists CustomerDeliveryList[]
  Addresses Address[]
  UserNairaAccounts UserNairaAccount[]
  UserDollarAccounts UserDollarAccount[]
  Cards Card[]
  ActivityLogs activityLog[]
}
```

and `CustomerDelivery` below

```
   model CustomerDelivery {
  id Int @default(autoincrement()) @id
  DeliveryRate DeliveryRate? @relation(fields: [delivery_rate_id], references: [id])
  delivery_rate_id Int?
  Customer User @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id])
  customer_id Int
  status DeliveryStatus @default(active)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  deleted_at DateTime?
  CustomerDeliveryGoods CustomerDeliveryGoods[]
  CustomerDeliveryListToCustomerDelivery CustomerDeliveryListToCustomerDelivery[]
}
```

Now here is the challenge. I want to get users with active (where status = active) customerDelivery.

prisma doc says below is correct:

```
eturn await this.db.user.findMany({
        where: {
            CustomerDeliveries: {
                some: {
                    status: {
                        equals: 'active'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        orderBy: {
            created_at: 'desc'
        },
        include: {
            CustomerDeliveries: true
        },
        skip: offset,
        take: limit
    })
```

Above code compiles well, but throws an error during run time. Error below

```
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `this.db.user.findMany()` invocation in
/Users/macbook/Desktop/cart/src/users/user.repository.ts:390:35

  387 })
  388 
  389 
→ 390 return await this.db.user.findMany({
        where: {
          CustomerDeliveries: {
            some: {
            ~~~~
              status: {
                equals: 'active'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        orderBy: {
          created_at: 'desc'
        },
        include: {
          CustomerDeliveries: true
        },
        skip: 0,
        take: 50
      })

Unknown arg `some` in where.CustomerDeliveries.some for type 
CustomerDeliveryListRelationFilter. Did you mean `is`? Available args:
type CustomerDeliveryListRelationFilter {
  is?: CustomerDeliveryListWhereInput | Null
  isNot?: CustomerDeliveryListWhereInput | Null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to version 5 and the issue went away.